# Which MySQL Replication should I use?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have two servers consider server 1 and server 2. There are many databases on server 1 and few active databases on server 2 as well.

Can I setup MySQL replication of server 1 and server 2. If yes, what type of replication is suggested Master-Master or Master-Slave.

I also wish to know if I go for Master-Slave replication will my Slave work as it is working currently or will there be limitations on operations that can be performed on Slave server. I read on some forum that Slave is able to perform only Read operations, so I wish to know if I go Master-Slave will I be able to use existing databases on Server 2(Slave).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used a Master Slave replication for many years exp on distibuited network, but I suggest you a solution based on GALERA http://galeracluster.com/products/ it used also inside openstack , it's  absolute the best one comparing to Master to master for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At this time I can't use third party tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in large part will be "It depends". Are you replicating to take backups from Slaves? Are you replicating to have Slaves provide read servicing for your application? Do you need read-after-write consistency? Are you replicating for high availability?

However you may want to investigate MySQL 5.7's new capability of [multi-source replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source-overview.html) since you have two database servers. i.e. Two Masters replicating to a Slave.

Comment: I want to use server 2 to take backups of server 1 and also want to use server 2 for its existing databases. I want server 2 to allow both read and write operations.

Comment: With multi-source replication you could take backups of server 1 (Master) & server 2 (Master) off of the Slave (server 3) which is a best practice (i.e. rather than an operational DB server). Both server 1 & server 2 would allow read and write operations.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused about MySQL replication modes. They are all Master/Master or Master/Slave. The first choice to make is whether you want to use asynchronous, semi-synchronous or synchronous replication. The former is available on all platforms out-of-the-box, but does have technical limitations. The latter needs additional components. How you then designate nodes within the cluster is a secondary question. A full discussion of these goes way beyond the scope of an answer here (but I suspect that you should probably try asynchronous master/master).

There are lots of good articles on the internet and a few good books on the topic (although not much yet available on semi-synchronous replication).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think you are correct, I need asynchronous master/master. I will search further for this.